# Key is logically stuck

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard

I have a system running Debian 12 where it appears that the alt key is logically stuck.

It is absolutely not the physical keyboard, I tested this extensively, and it appears alt is held down even with no keyboard plugged in.

How do I resolve this without restarting x.org or my system? Even if I have to ssh in, compile and run some c code as root, I need a fix for this that doesn't involve rebooting.

Comment: `doesn't involve rebooting` I take it rebooting does fix it though, and it's something that re-occurs after you do reboot. Have you tried disconnecting the keyboard and reconnecting it? Does connecting a different keyboard (after removing current one) also exhibit the same issue?

Comment: I have tried disconnecting and reconnecting the keyboard a few times, yes, and I have tried a different keyboard. The alt key is logically stuck in Linux, it has nothing to do with the physical keyboard. And yes, rebooting does fix it but it costs me several hours of work, no lost data, but trying to restore workflows in specific applications, too much to go into here, it's an enormous amount of lost time for something that simply shouldn't happen in a modern operating system, especially when the entire reason I run Linux is for stability and to minimize reboots.

Comment: OK .. but does rebooting solve it, and then the problem comes back?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but the occurrence is rare-ish and I can't repro

Comment: OK, that sort of information is useful

Comment: Understood, thank you!

Comment: `xdotool keyup Alt`

Comment: I assume you have tried tapping both Alt keys? After reboot does it reoccur after pressing the Alt key, or does it engage without such provocation?

Comment: does it happen only when using a specific application? or at any time regardless of what you're running? also, what window manager/desktop environment are you using (gnome? kde? xfce? other?), and are you using wayland or X?   (this doesn't sound like something that X or wayland would do, but could be triggered by an app or the WM/DE or an applet)

Comment: This could be an Accessibility option - some people require sticky shift/alt/ctrl keys.   I know that in xfce, under Settings -> Accessibility -> Keyboard, there's an option for sticky modifier keys, and I expect that other WMs/DEs have it too.   Check if that's turned on and turn it off if it is.